# Get Google OAuth2 authorised accounts

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I have authorised multiple accounts via Google's OAuth2. How do I get a list of accounts that I have authorised? I want to be able to revoke access.

To make it clearer, I go through the OAuth2 flow multiple times, each time selecting a different account. Then, I get the access/refresh token and save it to my database. By doing that, I noticed that I still get access to resources not tied to the latest account but also those that are tied to previously authorised accounts. I want to be able to list and allow my users to revoke access to these accounts.

Comment: When you say "I get the access/refresh token and save it to my database", are you saving every Refresh Token? or are you only saving some and discarding others? Your question implies the latter, but I don't quite understand why you would request authorization and then not save the token.

Comment: @pinoyyid Every user has their own token. Whenever he performs a OAuth2 authentication, the new token overwrites the existing one. I am confused because some resources seem to be accessible by multiple tokens although it's not supposed to be. I am not sure if it's my problem or if the API (GMB API) is designed that way. I've posted here too: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-My-Business-API/Designing-application-for-multiple-users/td-p/1121514

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "token". In Google Oauth there are Refresh Tokens and there are Access Tokens. These have different purposes and characteristics. Can I suggest you edit your question to be specific which tokens you are saving. Also clarify what you mean by "user" and by "account". In Google, user=account, but you seem to be saying that a user has more than one account. Again, it would be helpful if you could add more information to your question so it's clear what you're asking.

Comment: In my case, I am using the PHP library I pass in the array containing both tokens. I am not sure how this has any implications on the access rights. As for users, I meant my application users.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a list of the users who have authenticated your application.   I have this problems as well because I have a number of users who are still using a very old version of my application who i would like to inform them they should upgrade but i cant as i have no contact to them.

**Revoking access of known users:**

Your application can have as many users as you want authorized to it.  The refresh token gives you access to each of the users data.    The access will remain until the user revokes it or the refresh token hasn't been used for six months.

You can revoke it programmaticly by [revoking the token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke)

Try using:

```
$client->revokeToken();
```

This should revoke the old access given by a user. You will have to load the old refresh token into the client of course.

Comment: Your answer seems to suggest that I can only revoke the whole token. To clarify, what I am asking: An user in my application (holds a single token) can go through OAuth2 with multiple Google accounts hence "authorising" access to various services with multiple accounts. But I want to be able to selectively "de-authorise" some Google accounts tied to this token. Is that not possible?

Comment: When a user authenticates your application it is to a single google account.   Each google account will have a refresh token assigned to it (there can actually be several outstanding refresh tokens for a single user).   You need the refresh token to revoke it.   Not the actual google account.   No what you want to do is probably not possible unless you kept track of the refresh tokens for the different google accounts.

Comment: To be clear his token is tied to a single google account.